# Unable to annotate a generic identity function with JSDoc

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, jsdoc

I expected the following to work:

```js
// @ts-check

/**
 * @template A
 * @callback Identity
 * @param {A} a
 * @returns A
 */

/**
 * @template A
 * @type {Identity<A>}
 */
const id = (a) => a

/**
 * @type {number}
 */
export const five = id(5);   // bang!
```

As I would have thought when calling `id` the generic `A` would have been applied to type `number`.

But `tsc` complains with:

```
error TS2322: Type 'A' is not assignable to type 'number'.
error TS2345: Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'A'.
  'A' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'number'.
```

Answer (score 0):

i think the reason why the code you provided doesn't work is because the `JSDoc @template` tag doesn't affect the type of the function itself. It only affects the type of the function's parameters and return value. In your code, the function `id` is defined as a generic function, but it's not actually passed any generic type parameters. So, the type of `id` is `(a: any) => any`. This means that when you call `id(5)`, TypeScript doesn't know what type to assign to a. It could be any type, including number, so TypeScript can't infer that five should be of type number.

To fix this, you need to pass a generic type parameter to `id` when you call it. For example, you could do the following:

```
const five = id<number>(5);
```

This tells TypeScript that the type of a when calling id is number, so it can infer that five should be of type number.

Here is the complete code that works:

```
// @ts-check

/**
 * @template A
 * @callback Identity
 * @param {A} a
 * @returns A
 */

/**
 * @template A
 */
const id = <A>(a: A) => a;

/**
 * @type {number}
 */
export const five = id<number>(5);
```

Comment: Ahh interesting, thanks! I should have been more specific in my question though that I'm actually after a pure `.js` solution here, is that possible?

Comment: Ahh looks like it might not be supported: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27387#issuecomment-659671940